# Need help writing a for loop to create a border around a string

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, border

Hello I am wondering how to write a for loop that will create a border around a string. I have several strings at different lengths and I'd like the loop to print the string with a border surrounding it so it looks more cohesive and so I wont have to change it manually. Thanks!!

I need to get the "fortune" surrounded by a border as shown below but using a for loop.

here are the choosen fortunes:

A new opportunity awaits you at the fork of the road,

The early bird gets the worm, but the second mouse gets the cheese,

You are cleverly disguised as responsible adult,

The best things in life aren't things,

Forget injuries; never forget kindnesses,

Borrow money from a pessimist, They don't expect it back

```
cout << " |=========================================================| \n";
cout << " |" <<fortune[rand_index]<<" | \n";
cout << " |=========================================================| \n";
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Without any code it is much harder to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Find the length of the string and use that to figure out how many equal signs you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>

void print_with_border(std::string const &str)
{
    std::cout.put('+');

    for (std::size_t i{}; i < str.length() + 2; ++i)
        std::cout.put('-');

    std::cout << "+\n| " << str << " |\n+";

    for (std::size_t i{}; i < str.length() + 2; ++i)
        std::cout.put('-');

    std::cout << "+\n";
}


int main()
{
    std::string fortunes[]{
        "A new opportunity awaits you at the fork of the road.",
        "The early bird gets the worm, but the second mouse gets the cheese.",
        "You are cleverly disguised as responsible adult.",
        "The best things in life aren't things.",
        "Forget injuries; never forget kindnesses.",
        "Borrow money from a pessimist, They don't expect it back."
    };


    for (auto const &f : fortunes)
        print_with_border(f);
}
```

#### Output:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| A new opportunity awaits you at the fork of the road. |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| The early bird gets the worm, but the second mouse gets the cheese. |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
+--------------------------------------------------+
| You are cleverly disguised as responsible adult. |
+--------------------------------------------------+
+----------------------------------------+
| The best things in life aren't things. |
+----------------------------------------+
+-------------------------------------------+
| Forget injuries; never forget kindnesses. |
+-------------------------------------------+
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Borrow money from a pessimist, They don't expect it back. |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```